# how to find network interface index number using java program in ubuntu

Tags: java, networking, indexing, interface, java-native-interface

i am not able to get the index of my device driver that i need to.please help me if there is any other source code to get the index of the device driver (ARC0) .

Comment: Read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand what kind of question you can ask.

Comment: I think i have asked a question what i need to know the answer Manmohan_singh